# Eclipse workspace error

Tags: eclipse, workspaces

The errors below are what I get when I try to select a workspace to work with in eclipse.

> `Could not launch the product because the specified workspace cannot be created. The specified workspace directory is either invalid or read only.`

If I press 'Ok' I get this:

> `The default workspace '/var/www' is in use or cannot be created. Please choose a different one.`

Kindly help me out.

Comment: Update links to your image. We can not access your `/home` :P

Comment: Sorry about that. The images are not uploading. I have typed out the error. Please check the question again.

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions in the error message i.e. choosing a different workspace directory? you should normally choose a location that is in your user's home directory rather than a system directory such as /var/www

Comment: I have worked in /var/www before. I reinstalled my ubuntu and trying to get my work environment back. So on launching eclipse and trying to select my preferred workspace I get that error.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you do not have enough permissions to access to the folder. 
Try to use sudo command.

cd eclipse

sudo ./eclipse